# Looking for a clearer Carp::croak()

Tags: perl

I recently noticed that I'm prepending `__PACKAGE__` and sub/method name to most `croak()`'s messages because it makes tracking down errors easier. So I started writing a _croak() wrapper that adds this by default (using `caller(1)`).

E.g.

```
sub _croak {
    my ($msg) = shift // '';
    $msg = (caller 1)[3].': '.$msg
        unless ref $msg;
    Carp::croak($msg);
};
```

Now every (textual) exception is attributed both to the point where my module was misused (e.g. bad parameter passed), *and* to the module itself.

And the question: is there a standard module/technique for this? (Full stack traces aka confess() are overkill most of the time).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting [`croak`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp) to add caller information, I let my logger do it. [Log4perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl) let's me set the format for the messages I care to log. `croak` does its job, and the logger lets me peek at what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

A standard technique is to keep generating simple exceptions, and turn them into stacktraces only when needed by loading [Carp::Always](http://p3rl.org/Carp%3a%3aAlways)[::Color](http://p3rl.org/Carp%3a%3aAlways%3a%3aColor) from the command-line.